# Shell scripting - How to put the output of command into array?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have executed a command that returns something like

```
INFO: AAA.CSV; Date: 2021-09-17 08:35:02 +0000 GMT; Content Length: 74.00 B
INFO: BBB.CSV; Date: 2021-09-21 07:35:02 +0000 GMT; Content Length: 73.00 B
```

Now I want to fetching all the data in a loop

```
return_data_arr=($(MY_COMMAND))
for data in "${return_data_arr[@]}"; do
    echo -e "data: ${data}"
done
```

My expecting result is

```
data: INFO: AAA.CSV; Date: 2021-09-17 08:35:02 +0000 GMT; Content Length: 74.00 B
data: INFO: BBB.CSV; Date: 2021-09-21 07:35:02 +0000 GMT; Content Length: 73.00 B
```

But at the end, it comes up with

```
data: INFO:
data: AAA.CSV;
data: Date:
data: 2021-09-17
data: 08:35:02
data: +0000
data: GMT;
data: Content
data: Length:
data: 74.00
data: B
data: INFO:
data: BBB.CSV;
data: Date:
data: 2021-09-21
data: 07:35:02
data: +0000
data: GMT;
data: Content
data: Length:
data: 73.00
data: B
```

Comment: `it comes up with` so you succeeded to put it in an array.

Comment: Yes, it did push into the array, but it has been split by space. What I expected is to put the full output into it (just two data in array)